# CloudFoundry: Could not resolve placeholder 'cloud.services.rabbitmq.credentials.username'

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-cloud, cloud-foundry

I'm running a `Spring Boot` application on `PCF`. The application gets its configuration from a `Spring Cloud Config Server` which is running as a `PCF` service and bound to the application.

Here's a snippet of the configuration:

```
rabbit:
  internal:
    username: \${cloud.services.rabbitmq.credentials.username}
```

I now also bound the `rabbitmq` service to the application, but when I start the application I get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'cloud.services.rabbitmq.credentials.username' in value "\${cloud.services.rabbitmq.credentials.username}"
```

I added the dependencies mentioned in the [PCF docs](https://docs.pivotal.io/pivotalcf/1-8/buildpacks/java/spring-service-bindings.html). I also tried it with the `CloudPropertiesConfig` mentioned in the docs.

What am I missing?

Note: I only wan't to read the properties, I don't want to autoconfigure the rabbitmq since I have other rabbitmq instances, and hence multiple `ConnectionFactory`'s.

Versions:
PCF: 1.11
Spring Boot: 1.5.2

Comment: Two questions, are you using Spring Cloud Services? If so, you should seek help via the defined channels. What the slash before the dollar sign?

Answer (score 0):

I met the same issue and still trying to find out the root cause. As a temporary solution, read the configuration explicitly solved my problem.

```
private String username;

@Autowired
private Environment env;

@PostContruct
public void init() {
  username = env.getProperty("rabbit.internal.username");
}
```